# Collections.Sort reverses unexpectedly the "should be sorting output"

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I'm sorting an `ArrayList` based on 3 criterias : type - subtype - default flag, 
Now everything works fine except for when it comes to comparing the `default Boolean flags`, when I return `-1` on my `Comparator.compare` method it actually behaves like I returned `1` and viceversa.

This is the wanted order :

```
if E and R : 
    show E before R
if A and R : 
    show R before A
if E and A
    if A is default
        show A before E
    else 
        show E before A
```

I have 3 different types of cards : `E - R - A` (`R` being a type of `E`)

There is my Card code :

```
public class Card {

    public enum Type {
        E("E-Type"),
        A("A-Type"),
        Other("Other");

        ....
    }

    private String cuid;
    private boolean isDefault;
    private String ref;
    private Type type;
    ............

    // getters and setters

    public Boolean isDefault() {
        return isDefault;
    }

    public void setDefault(boolean isDefault) {
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
    }
}
```

So here I'm populating the list :

```
private static void populateCards () {
    Card eCard  = new Card ();
    Card rCard  = new Card ();
    Card aCard  = new Card ();

    eCard.setCuid ("eCard");
    rCard.setCuid ("rCard");
    aCard.setCuid ("aCard");

    eCard.setType (Card.Type.E);
    rCard.setType (Card.Type.E);
    aCard.setType (Card.Type.A);

    rCard.setRef ("ref");

    aCard.setDefault (true);

    // failing sorting case only with these 2 
    cards.add (aCard);
    cards.add (eCard);
}
```

here is my comparator code :

```
Comparator<Card> comparator = new Comparator<Card> () {

    @Override
    public int compare (Card card1, Card card2) {

        if (cards.size () < 2) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (cards.size () == 2) {
            // E vs R
            if (card1.getType ().equals (card2.getType ())) {                       
                if (card1.getRef () == null) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            // if (R vs A) else (E vs A)
            if (card1.getRef != null || card2.getRef () != null) {
                return - card1.getType ().toString ().compareTo (card2.getType ().toString ());
            } else {
                if (card1.isDefault ()) {
                    // comes here successfully when card1 is Default
                    // ISSUE HERE it processes 1 as : show card2 before card1
                    return 1;
                } else if (card2.isDefault ()) {
                    // comes here successfully when card2 is Default
                    // ISSUE HERE it processes -1 as : show card1 before card2
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return - card1.getType ().toString ().compareTo (card2.getType ().toString ());
                }
            }
        }

        ......................
    }
};

Collections.sort (cards, comparator);
```

So my issue here is related to this code :

```
if (card1.isDefault ()) {
    // comes here successfully when card1 is Default
    // ISSUE HERE it processes 1 as : show card2 before card1
    return 1;
} else if (card2.isDefault ()) {
    // comes here successfully when card2 is Default
    // ISSUE HERE it processes -1 as : show card1 before card2
    return -1;
} else {
    return - card1.getType ().toString ().compareTo (card2.getType ().toString ());
}
```

Why does it treat `1` or `-1` as the opposite of what they should be ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you test your comparator (unit test) and check that it actually performed the way you intend it to perform?

Comment: @fge : that's what I'm doing, it performs the way it should be for every case except the 2 last ones.

Comment: `if (cards.size () < 2)` -- bad idea and completely unnecessary.  `if (cards.size () < 2)` -- another bad idea and not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  `..............` -- This is probably where the problem is and you've omitted the code.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks. On the `........` there is no code left only a return for now. I haven't reached that yet. I'll remove the `if (cards.size () < 2` thanks for pointing it out, for `if (cards.size () == 2` it's necessary as the sorting logic is different when there is only 2 cards and when there is more than 2 (the `..........` part that I haven't reached yet).
Check my edited answer (code comments)

Comment: What is the source of `isDefault`? I think you should show the `Card` source in general.

Comment: You return `-1` which indicates that `Card1` is smaller when compared to `Card2` and when you return `1` it indicates `Card1` is greater than `Card2` and hence the results. What is the issue here? Am I missing something?

Comment: @RealSkeptic : basic getter / setter, it actually enters to the condition block

Comment: @user2004685 : I'm aware, when `-1` it shows `Card2` before `Card1`

Comment: @Copernic Sorry but when `-1` it should show `Card1` before `Card2` right?

Comment: By your code, if `card1.isDefault()` it returns 1. This means that `card1` is considered greater than `card2`. So it shows `card2` before `card1` when they are sorted. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @Copernic your code is sufficiently complicated that it'd be worth trying to keep it as simple as possible. You may well be better off creating a different `Comparator` for the case where there are only two cards, instead of trying to shoehorn different behavior into one `Comparator`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman : you're right, I'm lost with all the cases.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : please check my edited answer for the wanted order.

Comment: @RealSkeptic : question* sorry I haven't slept the last 38 hours .. :)

Comment: Your `if` doesn't reflect the question whether it's an `E` or an `A` card. It just checks `card1` and `card2`. So if `card1` is default, it's the bigger card, and it will be shown **later** in the sorted list. Since you only marked the `A` card as default, this means that `A` is the bigger card and will be **later** in the sorted list. It's really unclear why you think it should be different. It is working as expected, but really, you should fix comparators as Louis Wasserman recommended.